# Understanding asymptotic complexity of these code fragments

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am not sure of the rules/procedure to follow when determining asymptotic complexity of methods. I know single declarations is O(1) and single loops are O(n) and nested loops are O(n^2). Things which are doubled are log_2(n) things which are quartered are log_4(n). And if we have a loop that's O(n) and a something inside of that which produces log(n) then that's nlog(n). But I am still unsure how to figure all that out. Do we focus on the user inputted 'n' variable value to determine asymptotic complexity or do we focus on the incrementing variable value 'i'.

Can someone please walk me through these examples and show how it's done.

Example1:

```
for (k = 0; k < n; k = k + 3)
   for (p = n; p > 6; p--)
    System.out.prtinln(p%2);
```

T(n) = ?

Asymptotic complexity + ?

Example2:

```
for (k = 0; k <= n/8; k++)
    System.out.println(k);
System.out.prtinln("Next");
for (p = n; p >= 1; p--)
    System.out.prtinln(p % 2);
```

T(n) = ?

Asymptotic complexity = ?

Example3:

```
for (i = n - 3; i < = n - 1; i++)
    System.out.println(i);
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
      System.out.prtinln(i + k);
```

T(n) = ?

Asymptotic complexity = ?

Example4:

```
for (a = 1; a <= n/3; a++)
  for (b = 1; b <= 2 * n; b++)
    System.out.println(a * b);
```

T(n) = ?

Asymptotic complexity = ?